# What's the appropriate HTTP status code when the request is missing a required cookie?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-status

I have an API endpoint and the request should have a cookie (not authentication). What would be the correct HTTP status code to return if it isn't present?

I would assume a `400` Bad Request would be the best.

Comment: http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/

Comment: That is a very helpful post, thank you.  I will say that it doesn't seem to answer my question.  I get to the 400 level and see a list of headers, cookies are stored in the set-cookie header, and I don't see that in the list.

Comment: Seems like there should be a "Resend With Cookie" and a Resend-Cookie-For-Domain header.  Browsers could be configured by default to prompt if the cookie should be sent. People could trade off between maximizing privacy and maximizing availability of advertiser-financed services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No much details are provided in your question, but I guess `400` (Bad Request) is a good option:

> [**6.5.1. 400 Bad Request**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)
>
> The `400` (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

However, depending on your requirements, you also could consider the `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code, defined in the WebDAV specification, which is just an extension of the HTTP protocol:

> [**11.2. 422 Unprocessable Entity**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2)
>
> The `422` (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> `415` (Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a `400` (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

---

Just remember providing a good description in the response payload explaining what's missing in the request.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a [403 forbidden](https://httpstatuses.com/403) status code for this situation - where everything else is fine but the request is missing a cookie. To copy its details from the linked reference:

> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access

Status [401 unauthorized](https://httpstatuses.com/401) is for when the request lacks authentication credentials. But 401 also requires the response to contain a *WWW-Authenticate header field*. Based on the question, the request should have a cookie but doesn't, and it isn't a matter of authentication.

[Status 400](https://httpstatuses.com/400) is when the client request was erroneous, which might be a bit misleading for the scenario the OP describes.

[Status 422](https://httpstatuses.com/422) might be appropriate, but I think, a bit too generic since it means something on the lines of *everything was okay, but the server is unable to process the request*.

Comment: It might be helpful if the downvoter were to explain their downvote instead of downvoting willy-nilly...

Comment: IMO 403 might be the correct status code, if the cookie is meant for authentication or authorization